# How to find a function in an assembly in C# by its name and argument types?

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, runtime

I have as input a managed assembly 'some.dll', a function name and the types it takes as arguments. How can I find such function using a .NET C# 4.6 application at run-time?

Comment: What do you mean 'find it at runtime'?

Comment: You need to explain better what you have and what you want to do. This is completely unclear even as an English question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you are looking for reflection

This is a totally unrealistic example. However

**Given**

```
// Assembly1.dll
namespace TestAssembly
{
   public class Main
   {
      public void Run(string parameters)
      {
         // Do something... 
      }
      public void TestNoParameters()
      {
         // Do something... 
      }
   }
}
```

**You could do**

```
public object Test(string methodName)
{
   var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("...Assembly1.dll");
   var type = assembly.GetType("TestAssembly.Main");

   if (type == null)
   {
      return null;
   }

   var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);

   if (methodInfo == null)
   {
      return null;
   }

   var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();
   var classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);

   if (parameters.Length == 0)
   {
      methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, null);
   }
   else
   {
      var parametersArray = new object[] { "Hello" };           
      return  methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, parametersArray);
   }

   return null;
}
```

**Note** : You could programmatically iterate the contents as well and heuristically find what the classes and methods you are looking for